# PHP Infinite While loop to terminate

Tags: php, while-loop

I am new to PHP and I am having trouble with making this infinite while loop work. I am trying to make a infinite while loop generate random numbers between 1 and 10 and to output the cube root of those numbers, as well as terminating the loop when 5 is generated. So far I have the code below and I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any help or guidance will be much appreciated.

```
$counter = rand(1, 10);
while ($counter==5) {
    break; 
    if ($counter >5 or $counter<5) { 
        echo sqrt($counter) . "</br>"; 
    } 
    $counter++;
}
```

EDIT: I have listened to the advice you guys gave to me below and I noticed some mistakes I had made myself such as "or" becoming "and". However I am still yet to understand why it isn't generating a loop with numbers 1-10 to their powers?

```
while(true)
{
$counter = rand(1, 10);    
    if ($counter <=10) { 
        echo sqrt($counter) . "</br>"; 
    }
if($counter ==5) break;
}
```

Comment: You while loop would only ever even start to do a first iteration, if the random value happened to be 5. But then you don't care and don't want to do anything if that iteration was to actually happen - you break out of the loop first thing no matter what. And if you didn't do that, you continue doing stuff that makes no sense, by then checking whether that random value, that had to be 5 to even get us this far, was either greater than or lesser than 5. Logic not much your thing?

Comment: I'm learning mate. I understand what you are saying. Does that mean my use of an if statement in this problem is irrelevant?

Comment: The if is superfluous, you just need to get your while loop condition right. The loop ends, once the condition is _not_ met any more, so that of course has to be `$counter!=5`. Still leaves the problem that your while loop won't even start 9 out of 10 times, if the initially generated random value happens not to be 5. You want to use a `do ... while` loop for this - that always runs at least one time, and only checks the condition after the loop body has run. You also neglected to ever create a _new_ random value, you did that only once. That part belongs into the do while loop, first thing.

Comment: Thanks, i'll change the code to suit this

Comment: _"However I am still yet to understand why it isn't generating a loop with numbers 1-10 to their powers?"_ - because unless you got yourself a quantum computer, the counter is never gonna be greater five and lesser five at the same time, which your if condition still demands.

Comment: OHHH! I understand what you mean now. So if I was to put less than or equal to 10, would the program generate random integers between 1 and 10, then terminating at 5?

Answer (score 2):

you are breaking the loop WHILE (ongoing) your counter equals 5 and only echo once IF your condition is met.
what you might want to do could look like

```
while(true)
 {
   $counter = rand(1 , 10);
   #echo stuff
   if($counter == 5) break;
  }
```

Comment: I understand what you mean! I changed the code to suit this more however I still am unable to get the numbers generated to their powers.